# LibCurl HTTPS credentials, sequence internally handled?

Tags: c++, ssl, libcurl, credentials

hopefully someone can answer this for me as I'm beating my head against the wall.  I'm using LibCurl to do a simple file post to an HTTPS URL.  Overall, it works, however contacting the site receiving the post, they apparently have an issue resolved, and I just don't get it.

Apparently, I prepare my request, put the URL, provide USER and PASSWORD for the site.  The post then includes a CURL_FORMADD( for the parameters to add a single file attachment via multi-part form).

I had problems working out the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and finally got it working with the following settings.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
```

Here's the problem.  Apparently, when I issue the curl_easy_perform(), it tries to send the request, the response comes back and says ... send me the certificate information and then apparently re-submits the entire package WITH the cert info.  And then is accepted by the server I'm sending to.

So, how can I tell LibCurl to submit EVERYTHING... User, Password AND Certificate credentials all up front so the server I'm sending to doesn't reject the first request only to get the credentials the subsequent cycle.

Thanks.

---- EDITING via feedback.

While looking into more as mentioned by Eugen...

I've disabled the "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" from other readings that by doing so can open a transaction up to a "man-in-the-middle" compromise.  I don't want that.  By finding the method of authentication, it is BASIC, so when I am issuing the connection, I am sending along

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
```

Now, it comes back with CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR.  I'm trying to get the sdterror, but that's crashing via...

```
FILE  *pLocalFile;
if( fopen_s( &pLocalFile, "MyHTTPS.Log", "w" ))
    return -1;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L ); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteFileCallback ); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, pLocalFile );
```

As soon as I do the perform, I get the DLL caused an exception.  So, I cant' even see what the connection failure is about .. which I strongly suspect is certificates.

Comment: What kind of authentication does the site uses (Basic, NTLM, custom with cookies & such, etc.)? The reason I ask is that it may be that libcurl tries to figure out first what authentication methods are supported by the server - so it does a simple request without sending the user/pass - then it figures out what's available from the 401 reply. Although the SSL part makes things a bit confusing...

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca, Its certificate based is all I know, I guess I'll check with my supervisor in the morning.

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca, It's basic authentication, so I guess I'm now into providing certificate information...

Comment: A few things to clarify: since it looks like you're going over HTTPS the first thing that happens is the SSL handshake. At this point none of the USER, PASSWORD or the form data is being sent. During handshake you don't care to verify the server's certificate chain against a root CA store (CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=0) and you only care if the hostname matches the certificate' CN (CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=1). After the handshake is completed you get to send the USER, PASSWORD & the form data.

Comment: There's no way to skip the SSL handshake (at least not until the secure connection is established) so to skip getting server's certificate and send the USER, PASSWORD & the form data directly. Did you set the CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH option to CURLAUTH_BASIC (or any other value)? Otherwise libcurl will probably send the request as such and figure out from the 401 reply what kind of authentication the server wants (so it sends the request twice, without and with the USER, PASSWORD).

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca, updated message per your feedback

Comment: If you've set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=1 (at least that's what I understand from the "I've disabled the..." part) you'll probably need to specify a Root CA store (it depends on how you build libcurl). Or you can specify one via the CURLOPT_CAINFO and use the one available here http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. Otherwise the SSL handshake will fail.

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca, if you can put your comments into an answer, I can give you credit for the solution... it was a combination of each element as you helped guide me through.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It wasn't much of answer anyway, just repeated abuse of the SO's comment system :) Glad you got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep things apart to make the solving of this easier.

First you fix your SSL connection/handshake so that you don't get any SSL related problems or errors.

Then you make sure you provide the necessary HTTP authentication stuff and set basic, and you should only need to do a single HTTP request to get the correct response (assuming that is truly what the server wants).

The "DLL caused an exception" seems to be a third problem and is independent of the other stuff. It's hard to tell why you get that as we don't have a complete picture of what you're doing.